# Using empty properties in JMeter's Non-GUI Mode

Tags: jmeter

I've been trying to create a simple test scenario in JMeter using the Non-GUI Mode (Command Line) with some configurable parameters. I was hoping that I would be able to omit the value of some of the properties but it didn't work how I had hoped.

Below is the command I'm using to run the tests:

```
[JMETER_HOME]\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t example\test.jmx -p shared\resources\jmeter.properties -q example\resources\user.properties -l example\results\result.jtl -JUSERS=1 -JRAMPUP=0 -JLOOPS=1 -JDURATION= -JSERVER=www.google.com.au -JPORT= -JURL=maps/
```

I would like to specify a more that one default values for a few of these fields. I would like the JMeter to try to first use the command line properties, then try to use the user.properties and then finally have a default value.

Something like `${__P(PORT,${__property(port)},"")}`

Comment: I should mention that I am getting the variables in the Test Plan Element under the User Variables section by adding a variable like `server` and giving it a value of `${__P(SERVER)}`.

Answer (score 2):

`${__P(PORT,"")}` won't work as expected (JMeter 3.1) but **`${__P(PORT,)}`** does the trick

omitting the second parameter (`${__P(PORT)}`) defaults to `1` ... which is rarely a desired result.

Comment: can you point to documentation which suggests we can leave the default to empty

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can make JMeter try to use value of variable entered from console then user and finally default value. But you can make it use value from console and if no value entered in console then JMeter uses default value. To achieve that you should specify value of you user defined variable as `${__P(name_of_parameter_from_console,default_value)}`. 
http://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/how-to-pass-command-line-properties-to-a-jmeter-testplan/

Comment: What if you want default_value="" ? Then what?

Comment: Do you mean empty string? Did you try to specify default value as ""? If leave default value empty -- it will be considered as null. If you specify it as "" -- then it is considered as string which has length equal to 0.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  It doesn't like quotes within the curly brackets.  It appears that the person who asked the question had the exact same issue also.

Comment: Hm, it should work. Do you specify default value like this http://clip2net.com/s/iJP2uK ?

Comment: Can we provide default value as null, will it look for null string or the actual null?

Comment: Passing  `null`  just works - simple and brilliant. The above should be the correct answer now...